# textbox issue regarding shrinking first time input text

Tags: javascript, jquery

i have a problem regarding the textbox.
i have done the textbox auto expandable but when i insert the text first time then the textbox shrink in size from their original size.but my requirement is that when my text is exceeding the text box length then it auto expand. my code is

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('.txtStyle').autogrow();
        });
</script>
```

pls somebody suggest how ot is possible

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try adding a **minHeight** to your autogrow:

```
$(document).ready (function() {
    $('.txtStyle').autogrow({
    minHeight: 20,
    lineHeight: 12
    });
})
```

Comment: in this condition the line height is maintain throughout the textbox
how can i make it possible
pls suggest me

Comment: What do you mean? I don't understand that question.

Answer (score 0):

textbox don't autogrow... because it is not capable of multi lines... use textarea instead...